# Visual Studio command prompt closes despite that I tried to stop it with cin.get()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

My following basic C++ code isn't working. When I run it in Visual Studio express, it just closes the command prompt after I enter the second number. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int num1, num2, answer;

    cout << " Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    answer = num1 * num1;
    cout << " the sum of the number is: " << answer << endl;

    cout << "Enter a 2nd number";
    cin >> num2;
    answer = answer + num2;
    cout << "The sum of the two numbers is: " << answer << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try putting a cin.get() after the first input too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are characters left in the input buffer.

Anyway you shouldn't add "tricky" commands to keep the console open (you have to remember to remove them from the "production" code).

You can run your program *Without debugger mode* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) and Visual Studio will keep the console application window open until you press a button (just check the settings in `Project -> Properties -> Linker -> System -> Sub System -> Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`).

Of course, if you are debugging (<kbd>F5</kbd>), a breakpoint on the `return 0;` is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is probably happening:

Last `cin.get()` reads the Enter key that you press after entering the second number. You need one more `cin.get()` so that the command prompt waits for you to press another key.